# How to tar the contents of a directory (vs the directory itself) using node

Tags: node.js, npm, tar

If I have a directory:

```
my_directory
  --file1
  --file2
  --file3
```

I can do this:

```
tar -cvf my_tar.tar my_directory/*
```

Is this possible with some node module like [`node-tar`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-tar) or [`tar-fs`](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-fs) or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer would be:

```
require('child_process').execFile('tar', ['-cvf','my_tar.tar','my_directory/*'])
```

Comment: It should work anywhere as long as tar executable is available. It doesn't seem like a "true" way (better to bind to `libtar` instead), but it is by far the easiest one.